# Is it possible to know the derived instance type during base class destruction in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor

Say I have pure class `A` and class `B`, `C`, `D`, etc. deriving from `A`. Is it possible to know from within the destructor of `A` which derived class is being destroyed?

Comment: I guess you mean automatically, that is, the compiler shall tell you? A "manual" solution is to add some data member that stores the most-derived type, e.g. a `type_info const&`.

Comment: No. By this point all derived parts are gone. Why do you need this?

Comment: i'd like to know if you could achieve the same ends by marking the base destructor as virtual and overriding the destructor in each of the derived classes

Comment: @Jimmy: Destructors are special in that respect, because the override B::~B is still going to call A::~A. Back in A::~A, you don't know where you came from.

Answer (score 4):

That depends on what you need. One would of course here question why, this is a questionable desire.

There's no possibility to at compile time to automatically know the dynamic type of the object from the base class at any time. If you want to know the type in compile time the only solution is to include that information in the base class type itself, which is basically the CRTP pattern. For example:

```
class BaseBase {
    // body
};

template <typename D>
class Base : BaseBase {
    //body
};

class Derived1 : public Base<Derived1> {
    // body
};

class Derived2 : public Base<Derived2> {
    // body
};
```

this way the destructor of `Base` will at compile time "know" the type of the derived class at compile time. However this has the disadvantage that the common super type of `Derived1` and `Derived2` is **not** `Base`, but `BaseBase` and `BaseBase` destructor can't know (and you may be back on square one).

If you want only to know at runtime (which means that you can't directly do things like `DerivedClass::something`) for example for debugging reasons you could add a member in the base class containing the type info:

```
class Base {
protected:
     type_info const* type;

public:
    Base() {
        type = &typeid(this);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
     Derived() {
          type = &typeid(this);
     }
};
```

Note that this relies on the fact that `Base` constructor will be run before `Derived` constructor so the `type` pointer will refer to the most derived class that currently has been constructed.

Comment: You forgot inheriting `Base` in the 2nd example :)

Answer (score 3):

Can be done when [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) is used, like this:

```
template <typename TDerived>
class Base {};

class Derived : public Base<Derived> {};
```

Then `Base` knows the derived type at all times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with CRTP is that you have *different* base types, which you can't use for dynamic polymorphism.

In case you don't need the actual type of the derived object, but want to execute code depending on it, there are different possibilities. Note that you cannot call any virtual functions in the destructor. However, you can:

1. Add a type member variable (be it `std::type_info`, an enum or whatever) and dispatch manually on it.

2. Use an technique as a counterpart to the [virtual constructor idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Virtual_Constructor), with a function being called before explicit destruction (through `delete` or similar). However, this either can be forgotten, or (if enforced) severely limits how you can destroy objects.

3. You can use a strategy pattern:

```
class Base
{
    struct Strategy
    { 
        virtual ~Strategy();
        virtual void onDestroy() = 0;
    }

    std::unique_ptr<Strategy> strategy;

public:
    explicit Base(std::unique_ptr<Strategy> strategy)
    : strategy(std::move(strategy))
    {
    }

    virtual ~Base()
    {
        strategy->onDestroy();
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
    struct Strategy1 : Strategy
    {
        virtual void onDestroy() { ... }
    };

public:
    Derived1()
    : Base(std::make_unique<Strategy1>())
    {
    }
};
```

Note that with C++11 function objects, this becomes fairly simple:

```
class Base
{
    std::function<void()> strategy;

public:
    explicit Base(std::function<void()> strategy)
    : strategy(std::move(strategy))
    {
    }

    virtual ~Base()
    {
        strategy();
    }
};

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    Derived1()
    : Base([] () { ... })
    {
    }
};
```

**Important:** You have to make sure that the strategy object or function object does not reference any members of the derived class, as the derived object has been destroyed at the time of invocation. If you need to access member properties, you'd be better off redefining the destructor directly.